# Silverlight and ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

Is it possible to call a page by using

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate("ShowMedia.aspx", "_blank");
```

from my silverlight code behind?

The ShowMedia.aspx is located in my

```
<projectName>.web
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:-

```
 HtmlPage.Window.Navigate("/ShowMedia.aspx", "_blank");
```

Comment: @xscape: Tweak the test page hosting your Silverlight app to contain a standard HTML anchor with the save URI as its HREF.  Test that it works there.  If so I can't explain why it doesn't work using `Window.Navigate`.